# SQL Calculate Availability Percentage

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an SQL Query to calculate the API Availability Percentage at millisecond level and aggregate at minute level.

Below is the formula along with the sample input data.

Step -1 : Calculate Difference of Max Error timestamp and Min Error Timestamp for each minute level

```
diff = ( max error timestamp - min error timestamp ) 
     = 300 -100
```

Step-2 : Calculate percentage Availability at each minute level as below

```
percentage Availability = (1 - ( diff/60000) ) * 100 

                        =  (1 - (200/60000) )* 100
                        =  99.66
```

Sample Input Data

```
+--------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------+
|  DateTime                | APIName            | Id                 | STATUS   |
+--------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------+
| 2020-02-02 01:09:00.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:09:00.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:09:59.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:09:59.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |

| 2020-02-02 01:10:00.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:00.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:01.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:01.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.026  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.074  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.100  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            | Error    |----> min error timestamp 
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.281  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.300  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            | Error    |----> max error timestamp
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.301  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.365  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:02.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:03.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:03.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:59.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:10:59.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |

| 2020-02-02 01:11:00.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:11:00.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:11:59.000  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
| 2020-02-02 01:11:59.999  | AccountAPI         | 2221654            |    OK    |
+--------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------+
```

Expected Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|    DateTime         | APIName     |   PerCent Available |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2020-02-02 01:10:00 | AccountAPI  |   100               |                         
| 2020-02-02 01:11:00 | AccountAPI  |   99.66             |
| 2020-02-02 01:12:00 | AccountAPI  |   1000              |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I leverage window functions to achieve this?

Comment: mysql or mssql?

Comment: Now we know what you need, what is the question? What is the specific problem you stuck with?

Comment: I need to use Windowing function in MySQL to achieve this @mkRabbani

Comment: @RaAm Then remove the sql-server tag.

Comment: What if there is only one `Error` in a minute? Is the availability still 100%?

Comment: @Nick then in that case Max time should be 999

Comment: @RaAm I'm not sure what you mean by "Max time should be 999"? What should percent availability be in that case?

Comment: @Nick, I mean , suppose if only one error of “ 2020-02-02 01:10:02.281” exists, then diff = 999 - 281 . Then we use the second formula to calculate percentage

Comment: @RaAm I see what you mean - but what if there are `OK` values between the error and `999`?

Comment: Since none of the answers are ANSI-SQL compliant, I have removed the <ansi-sql> tag. (MySQL has it own, non-standard set of date/time functions etc.)

Comment: @Nick, got your thought. In the case of only one Error, then many Ok. We need to calculate diff between Error & first Ok. I accept this is a weird.

Comment: @RaAm possibly weird, but you need some way to give an availability that's not 100%. I've updated my answer and demo to work it out that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to find the `MIN` and `MAX` times in each minute where there is an `Error` status, and then subtract those times to compute the percentage availability:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT DATE(DateTime) AS date, FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(DateTime)) / 60) AS minute,
         APIName,
         MIN(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Error' THEN DateTime END) AS min_error_ts,
         MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Error' THEN DateTime END) AS max_error_ts,
         MIN((SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM log l2 WHERE l2.DateTime > log.DateTime)) AS next_time
  FROM log
  GROUP BY date, minute, APIName
)
SELECT CONCAT(date, ' ', SEC_TO_TIME(minute * 60)) AS DateTime,
       APIName,
       CASE WHEN min_error_ts IS NULL OR max_error_ts IS NULL THEN 100
            WHEN min_error_ts = max_error_ts THEN 100 - TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, min_error_ts, next_time) / 600000
            ELSE 100 - TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, min_error_ts, max_error_ts) / 600000
       END AS `Percent Available`
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
DateTime                APIName     Percent Available
2020-02-02 01:09:00     AccountAPI  100
2020-02-02 01:10:00     AccountAPI  99.6667
2020-02-02 01:11:00     AccountAPI  100
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60d1eacf302ffd6873386e05d199bf94)

Answer (score 1):

Try this below logic

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:00"),
APIName,
(SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(STATUS))*100
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:00"),APIName;
```